# Is there a way to launch Terminal with a prefilled statement?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to open a terminal window with a statement. Is there a process I can run that will do this?

For example, I want to run a script that 1. Opens Terminal and 2. has the following statement:

> java -version

The user then can press the Enter key to run the statement

Comment: What do you mean by "prefilled statement"? The command line should contain a command already, but you still have to hit the "Enter" key? Or it should run a specific command every time it's opened?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It should open with a statement on the line but you have to press the enter key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by wrapping the command in a `.command` file that contains a command to `read` something, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
command="java -version"
echo $command
read input
exec $command
```

...then, make the script file executable by running `chmod +x filename.command` on the file that you put this in, and run it (e.g. from the Finder or by using `open filename.command`).  This should launch the terminal, print the command, and wait for the user to press Enter before running it.

You will note that since this is a script, you can customize any of the steps above to do whatever you want, e.g. printing more stuff or running other commands.